# Postgresql - how to duplicate a table with keeping the inheritance?

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, duplicates, create-table

Anyone know how to duplicate a table with keeping the inheritance?

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE modele.t_courtiers
(
  idcourtier serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT t_courtiers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idcourtier)
) INHERITS (public.t_users);
```

I run the query to duplicate the previous table in another schema

```
CREATE TABLE dams.t_courtiers
(
   LIKE modele.t_courtiers INCLUDING DEFAULTS INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS INCLUDING INDEXES INCLUDING STORAGE INCLUDING COMMENTS
);
```

I expected to have:

```
CREATE TABLE dams.t_courtiers
(
  idcourtier serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT t_courtiers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idcourtier)
) INHERITS (public.t_users);
```

But I got this :

```
CREATE TABLE dams.t_courtiers
(
  iduser integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('t_users_iduser_seq'::regclass),
  datecreate timestamp(0) without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  lastlogin timestamp(0) without time zone,
  email character varying(128),
  idcourtier integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('modele.t_courtiers_idcourtier_seq'::regclass),
  CONSTRAINT t_courtiers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idcourtier)
);
```

Postgres duplicate the table without the inherit criteria, just merge all columns.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried altering the table to force the inheritance after the create like?

```
ALTER TABLE dams.t_courtiers INHERIT public.t_users
```